# QRCode dose not appear when starting react-native project

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

I cloned a react-native project [react-native-multi-language-sample](https://github.com/appfoundry/react-native-multi-language-sample/tree/master/MultiLangSampleApp)
 but when I run it with `yarn start`, it runs the packager on port 8081 but do not show any QRCode. Do you have an idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to have been built using Expo, so it will not generate any QRCode to be read on your Expo app.

You might need to run it in your simulator/emulator/device using `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android`.

Hope it helps